# Node addon unable to snapshot (CreateToolhelp32Snapshot) modules

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, libv8

I'm trying to learn C++ but can't quite understand why when I attempt to snapshot modules via a Node add-on different results are returned to when I run the program through VS on the desktop.

Using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686701(v=vs.85).aspx) source from MSDN I can list all modules within a process:

```
void fm(LPSTR name) {
    HANDLE hModuleSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, 5844);
    MODULEENTRY32 mEntry;

    // check invalid handle value...
    // check module32first...

    mEntry.dwSize = sizeof(mEntry);

    do {
        if (!strcmp(mEntry.szModule, name)) {
            CloseHandle(hModuleSnapshot);
            cout << mEntry.szModule << endl;
        }
    } while (Module32Next(hModuleSnapshot, &mEntry));
}
```

This works as intended and will find/print the module information (error checking omitted) - however, when I try and port this functionality over to a Node add-on it does not list the same modules as the code above (the code is nearly identical, I don't know why attempting to implement the function inside a custom Node add-on affects the result):

```
void fm() { 
    HANDLE hModuleSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, 5844);
    MODULEENTRY32 mEntry;

    // check invalid handle value...
    // check module32first...

    mEntry.dwSize = sizeof(mEntry);

    do {
        cout << mEntry.szModule << endl;
    } while (Module32Next(hModuleSnapshot, &mEntry));

    CloseHandle(hModuleSnapshot);
}
```

After using node-gyp to compile the add-on I can call it successfully (after requiring, it simply runs a function that calls `fm`).

If I try to snapshot the process with the PID `5844` (VS Code) it prints out:

`Code.exe
ntdll.dll
wow64.dll
wow64win.dll
wow64cpu.dll`

If I try the process with the PID `6540` (Chrome) it prints out:

`chrome.exe
ntdll.dll
wow64.dll
wow64win.dll
wow64cpu.dll`

This is obviously not correct, it prints out the same modules even though the PID (hard coded) is differing.

If I use the first block of code and run it with VS, I get:

`chrome.exe
ntdll.dll
KERNEL32.DLL
KERNELBASE.dll
apphelp.dll
ADVAPI32.dll
msvcrt.dll
sechost.dll
RPCRT4.dll
SspiCli.dll
CRYPTBASE.dll...`
There's a lot more modules, but you can see this is what the second block of code should print.

I do not know why running the code through a custom Node add-on would affect the outcome unless I'm missing or not understanding something about Node add-ons.

I can open and collect information about all processes correctly using `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` with the Node add-on, but I can not seem to collect information on the modules within a process.

Comment: Why did you use `do ... while` instead of `while`?

Comment: No reason, why use `while` over `do while`?

Comment: I had not totally understood. You probably initialize the `mEntry` in the `// check ...` sections.

Comment: The Module32First in the `// check` looks like `if (!Module32First(hModuleSnapshot, &mEntry))...throw error`

Comment: Node is running in x64 and the process you are trying to open is prob x86.

Comment: Yeah, figured this out a while ago. Probably should've left an answer to update everyone, bit of a late reply to an inactive thread haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE` within a x64 process(Node.exe) on x86 process will give you only the 64 bit modules, use `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32` to get the 32 bit modules - `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32` for all modules.